# YET another question about installer for Java App

Tags: java, installation

I just read so many posts about installers for a Java App and I'd like to get some opinions as for the best choices. My requirements aren't too long. I just need:
- the installer to install Java, MySQL and run the database script file;
- create a shortcut for my Java App.

I'm most looking for open source/free choices.

Answer (score 1):

Look into [NSIS](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Main_Page). It's pretty easy to use, it can call out to other installers (so the user just has to follow those other dialogs to completion), and it can create shortcuts. It's actually quite powerful.

It generates installers for Windows only, though; no DEBs or RPMs.

Answer (score 0):

You may also want to check out [BitRock InstallBuilder](http://installbuilder.bitrock.com/)
(Disclaimer: I am one of the InstallBuilder developers)

It is not free, as you are looking for, but we offer free licenses for open source projects as well as discounts for solo-developers and small companies.

Per your requirements, InstallBuilder is capable of bundling a [Java
runtime](http://installbuilder.bitrock.com/docs/installbuilder-userguide/ar01s17.html#_bundling_a_jre), [autodetecting the one included in the system](http://installbuilder.bitrock.com/docs/installbuilder-userguide/ar01s17.html#java_autodetection), creating launchers and desktop shortcuts and so on.

Regarding MySQL we do not have built-in actions, but many of our customers bundle MySQL and is
relatively straightforward.